# How to add fields in django admin change page?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to some directions for this question. For example, I have three models: Country, State, City. In the admin:myapp_city_change url, I can change the city in a drop down list. However, the question is that there are too many choice in the list, which makes me hard to find. So I want to have three fields which are Country, State and City. These fields will be dependent drop down list so I can easily filter to the city I want.

How can I achieve this?

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
```

Comment: you can read [**this**](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) blog post. It explains clearly how to do chained dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) can be used for your instance, especially because it can be applied to the Admin side.

A more generic way of doing it (i.e., without the use of the Admin side) is explained here by Vitor on [SIBTC](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html).

Comment: The project I am working on has data in it. So if I use Django Smart Selects to change the field in model, the system may crash.

Comment: Solved this by adding new field using django-smart-select. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this blog post, [**Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django**](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html). It explains clearly how to do dependent/chained dropdown. It explains everything you need.

Comment: I have already read it but implementation in  admin page seems different.